# Python save panda to csv files separately within FOR loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, export-to-csv

I would like to save down some panda dataframe downloads separately as csv files. I am getting an error in the last line.

Is the syntax off?

Kind regards

```
sortedByISIN = pd.DataFrame()

for i in data['isin'].unique():
 print('Adding ' + i)
 d1 = data[data['isin'] == i]

 d1['next_signal'] = d1['signal'].shift(-1)

 #Shift x periods in the future 
 d1['futprice'] = d1['mid'].shift(-6)
 d1['futT'] = d1['creationTimeStamp'].shift(-6)


 d1['move'] = d1.apply(lambda row: (row['futprice'] - row['mid'])/row['mid'] * 10000 if row['futT'] - row['creationTimeStamp'] < 300000 else 0, axis=1)
 d1['signal_transition'] = d1['next_signal'] - d1['signal']

 sortedByISIN = sortedByISIN.append(d1)

 sortedByISIN['period'] = np.floor(sortedByISIN.creationTimeStamp/3600000)
 sortedByISIN.to_csv('Book'%i.csv')
```

Answer (score 2):

or you can use also:

```
sortedByISIN.to_csv('Book' + str(i) + '.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
sortedByISIN.to_csv('Book{}.csv'.format(i))
```

And for python `3.6+` is possible use `f-string`s:

```
sortedByISIN.to_csv(f'Book{i}.csv')
```